# Companding in DPCM

Tags: pcm, audio-processing

I'm learning about Speech Processing, and I want to know whether or not we can use Companding in DPCM? Based on what I've learned so far, Companding is used in PCM for compressing and then expanding an analog or digital signal, but I haven't seen anything about it being used in DPCM. Why is that?

Thank you